# Processing - Android mode not recognizing any function

Tags: java, processing

I have switched to Android mode in processing 3.3.

Processing is now not recognising any function I use, such as ellipse, stroke, background etc. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: More context? i.e. code

Comment: It sounds like you haven't included Processing on your classpath, but we need to see a [mcve] if we're going to help you.

Comment: @Gerimeni What version of Android Mode are you using ?

Comment: belive me i wrote what i tried to do and copy the wrror it give me really good latter. but i guess its not enugh for stack over flow and it just not give me to post it, no matter what am i did.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the latest Android beta from [releases](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/releases).
I had some (different) issues recently and this helped.

Here's what I did:

1. Close Processing
2. Delete Android Mode from `Documents/Processing/modes/`
3. Download [AndroidMode-257.zip](https://github.com/processing/processing-android/releases/download/android-258/AndroidMode-258.zip) (Version 4.0-beta5 of the Android mode)
4. Unzip to `Documents/Processing/modes/` (and double check the unzipped folder is called `AndroidMode` containing android-core.zip and the rest of the folders)
5. Start Processing and change to Android Mode.

You will be prompted to either point Processing to an existing Android SDK folder on your computer or download one for you. Because it need to use the latest Android SDK 25 and Google Services, etc. I recommend letting Processing handle the SDK Download for you. (It will take a bit (~800MB), but it will work)